# TYPO3 realURL and userfunction form

Tags: forms, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

I post data and redirect to another page with a userfunction and a simple form like the following example:

```
<?php
class user_test
{
   public function getForm() {

       $form = '
           <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
          </form>
       ';

        $postArray = t3lib_div::_POST();

        if ( isset( $postArray['send'] ) ) {
            header( 'Location: index.php?id=2' );
        }

        return $form;
    }
}
```

this works fine if realURL is deactivated, but if I activate realURL this form leads me always to the homepage after submit :(.

The typoscript part looks as follows:

```
 prefixLocalAnchors = all
 simulateStaticDocuments = 0
 baseURL = http://test.de
 tx_realurl_enable = 1
```

realURL works for speaking URLs and other forms like powermail forms, but my own forms leads to homepage, hope you can help me :).

**UPDATE**

If I remove the hash from action attribute: 'action="#"' of this form it is working, is this solution passable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the action attribute from the form was working.